# Calculating the inverse of a system of 4 simultaneous equations that deal with image conversion from image space to cortical space.

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations, polar-coordinates

I am completely stuck in calculating the inverse of these equations.

These equations show how to convert a image coordinate to a cortical coordinate (x,y being the image coordinate and alpha being a constant). However, I need to figure out how to calculate x,y given Xleft, Yleft, Xright, Yright. I am absolutely stuck at this because not even wolfram alpha seems to be able to do it.

Thank you!

[The equations I need help with.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/65qnt.png)

Comment: Do you really mean the inverse of the given system? Or want you to solve this system?

Comment: Hi Welcome to MSE. Please post the equations using MathJax rather than images

Comment: Possible solution. Apply $\tan$ to the last one. Then solve for $y$ in terms of $x$. Substitute in the first one, square, then you have a quadratic in $x$. Hope then that the two unused equations are right.

Comment: Hint: square Xleft and Xright, so that you can at least solve for x^2 and y^2, then use the remaining equations to determine their angular phases.

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner I am not sure if inverse is the right term for it. I want to solve them in terms of x and y which is the opposite of whats happening in the original equations.

Comment: @EthanBolker thanks I will try that.

Comment: @JohnJiang thank you for the suggestion.

Comment: In the future, please include relevant parts of your question as text instead of pasting in a picture of it. Images are neither searchable nor accessible to screen-reading software. You can find a quick reference and tutorial for formatting mathematical expressions with MathJax [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Answer (score 1):

First we do

$$X_{left}^2 = (x-\alpha)^2 + y^2 \tag 1$$

Then square $X_{right}$

$$X_{right}^2 = (x+\alpha)^2 + y^2 \tag 2$$

Subtracting $(1)$ from $(2)$

$$X_{right}^2 - X_{left}^2 = 4\alpha x$$

$$ x = \frac{X_{right}^2 - X_{left}^2}{4\alpha}$$

Similarly you can get $y$ by putting $x$ in any of the above equations

Comment: Thanks a lot! I will try it.

Comment: If it worked for you, could you please accept the answer?